# Multiple Release With Macro in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I hope this isn't a duplicate question. I tried searching, but had so many search results that were not relevant, I didn't have time to dig through them all.

I have a program that has few different versions each time I release. The differences are very small and I use a macro to control them. I want to know if it is possible to do something as follows:
1) Have some macros that are mapped to each release version, for example:
RELEASE_2

RELEASE_3

2) When visual studio compiles the program, it creates a program in the Release folder as it normally does. This release is compiled as if all my release specific macros are undefined.

3) Then visual will compile a version for each of my release specific macros. For example, a program will be output to the Release_2 folder and will be compiled as if RELEASE_2 is defined, and so on (Release_3 folder ...)

Is this possible?

Comment: Well, you could create multiple copies of the Release configuration, one for each special release type, and configure the output folder and preprocessor symbols (adding RELEASE_n) accordingly. I'm not sure how simple it would be to get them all to automatically compile one after another, though.

Comment: @Cameron Thanks! I found you can [batch build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj651644.aspx) so your suggestion should be sufficient in combination with that feature :-)